# how to specify path to usr/lib of a specific machine in makefile?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am using some libraries installed at my local machine in directory /usr/lib/. I want to run my program on another machine where the same libraries are installed but other version. How can I specify the path that the program runs on another machine but the libraries are used from my computer ?

Thanks

Comment: that's basically the job of ./configure scripts

Comment: Are the libraries in question shared or static?

Comment: I find the question very unclear. Are you compiling on your machine and deploying the binary? Or is the question about configuring the compile on the other machine?

Comment: the libraries are shared... I am compiling on my machine and then running on a different machine by connecting from my machine. I hope it becomes a bit clear.

Comment: I am connected to remote machine using ssh and then run the program there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure shell does not provide a service for finding binaries and libraries on the originating machine and running them on the remote machine (or indeed the other way 'round).

You *will* need to deploy the executable.

I'd suggest:

1. Compile on you home machine, linking the desired libraries *statically*. The static link is critical. You may need to read your compiler documentation to make this happen.
2. Copy the resulting binary to the remote machine (perhaps using `scp`).
3. Ssh to the remote machine and invoke the statically linked binaries.
4. ???
5. Profit.

Of course, this will only work if the two machines share a processor architecture and common executable format. That means, that linux-to-linux *will* work, and linux-to-some-other-unixy-OS *might* work (try a.out executable format), and linux-to-windows certainly *won't* work.

Answer (score 0):

well for that to be possible, your machine should be connected to a network which should be connected to all other machines.. and in your script, where you specify where to get the libraries from say /usr/lib....instead give your IP ADDRESS first and append the /Machintosh HD/usr/lib...i.e if your ip address is 192.168.2.4, then instead of giving /usr/lib, give

//192.168.2.7/Machintosh HD/usr/lib/codeorlibraryfile

if ur not connected to a network, this wont work other wise i dont see a reason this not working... check the "//" i m not sure in start if "\" will come or "//"..

hope this helps

Comment: it does not work while you are logged in using ssh... it only searches at the local machine which in my case is the remote machine.